# Hi i would like to take value for this three keys ('K','O','T')

Tags: java, loops, java-stream, getvalue

It is simple probably but I have no idea how to make it. Help
The problem is at the end of the code.

*****I would like to have a result like this **556668** and I've got like this:

**[2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333, 4, 44, 444, 5, 55, 555, 6, 66, 666, 7, 77, 777, 7777, 8, 88, 888, 9, 99, 999, 9999][2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333, 4, 44, 444, 5, 55, 555, 6, 66, 666, 7, 77, 777, 7777, 8, 88, 888, 9, 99, 999, 9999][2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333, 4, 44, 444, 5, 55, 555, 6, 66, 666, 7, 77, 777, 7777, 8, 88, 888, 9, 99, 999, 9999]****

---

**My code:**

```
changingLettersOnNumbersAndMap("KOT");



static public void changingLettersOnNumbersAndMap(String letters) {
    Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String numbers = "";

    map.put('A', "2");
    map.put('B', "22");
    map.put('C', "222");
    map.put('D', "3");
    map.put('E', "33");
    map.put('F', "333");
    map.put('G', "4");
    map.put('H', "44");
    map.put('I', "444");
    map.put('J', "5");
    map.put('K', "55");
    map.put('L', "555");
    map.put('M', "6");
    map.put('N', "66");
    map.put('O', "666");
    map.put('P', "7");
    map.put('Q', "77");
    map.put('R', "777");
    map.put('S', "7777");
    map.put('T', "8");
    map.put('U', "88");
    map.put('V', "888");
    map.put('W', "9");
    map.put('X', "99");
    map.put('Y', "999");
    map.put('Z', "9999");


    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
        char charAt = letters.charAt(i);
        if (map.containsKey(charAt)) {
            Collection<String> values = map.values();

            Set<Map.Entry<Character, String>> entries = map.entrySet();
            numbers = numbers + entries.stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify which `"three key"`, where they come from? Please consider [*editing the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73392143/edit) by explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Remove anything inside the if-block and append only the string from the map there: `numbers = numbers + map.get(charAt);`

Comment: You have not explained nearly enough for someone to adequately help.  We should not have to look at your code to figure out what you are trying to do.   Please provide more detail.

Comment: @Mihe thanks!!! it works I knew it was simple :)

Comment: You tagged your question java-stream. So: `String numbers = letters.chars() .mapToObj(ch -> Character.valueOf((char) ch)) .map(map::get) .filter(Objects::nonNull) .collect(Collectors.joining());`. Gives `556668`.

Answer (score 1):

- use a StringBuilder to house the result.
- then simply append the value for the required character.

```
String result = changingLettersOnNumbersAndMap("KOT");
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
556668



static public String changingLettersOnNumbersAndMap(String letters) {
   Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();

   map.put('A', "2");
   map.put('B', "22");
   map.put('C', "222");
   map.put('D', "3");
   map.put('E', "33");
   map.put('F', "333");
   map.put('G', "4");
   map.put('H', "44");
   map.put('I', "444");
   map.put('J', "5");
   map.put('K', "55");
   map.put('L', "555");
   map.put('M', "6");
   map.put('N', "66");
   map.put('O', "666");
   map.put('P', "7");
   map.put('Q', "77");
   map.put('R', "777");
   map.put('S', "7777");
   map.put('T', "8");
   map.put('U', "88");
   map.put('V', "888");
   map.put('W', "9");
   map.put('X', "99");
   map.put('Y', "999");
   map.put('Z', "9999");


   StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
       char charAt = letters.charAt(i);
       if (map.containsKey(charAt)) {
            numbers.append(map.get(charAt));
       }
    }

    return numbers.toString();
       
}
```

You would be better off creating the Map outside the method and passing it as an argument.  That way it only needs to be created once,.